# My homebrewed Python/pip is trying to install binaries in /usr... why, and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I'm running OSX 10.10.2, and an up to date homebrewed installation of Python 2.7.9. For some reason -- and because I rarely work outside of virtualenvs, and haven't created any recently, I can't say when this changed -- pip now tries to write its binaries to `/usr` instead of to the homebrew binary prefix. Below is the output from a pip upgrade of pip itself, along with versions/paths to the binaries. I can add anything from my environment that might help out with this.

```
~/projects/ideas $ pip install -U pip
Collecting pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=41e73fae2c86ba2270ff51c1d86f7e09
  Using cached pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 6.0.6
    Uninstalling pip-6.0.6:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-6.0.6

  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 347, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 549, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 751, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 960, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 344, in move_wheel_files
      generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 323, in make
      self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 227, in _make_script
      self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 201, in _write_script
      self._fileop.write_binary_file(outname, script_bytes)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py", line 388, in write_binary_file
      with open(path, 'wb') as f:
  IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/bin/pip'

~/projects/ideas $ which pip && pip --version
/usr/local/bin/pip
pip 6.0.6 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

~/projects/ideas $ which python && python --version
/usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.9
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question turns out to be the presence of `~/.pydistutils.cfg` which due to an attempt to tweak install paths had this in it:

```
[install]
prefix=
```

This was rewriting the prefix for all python package installs into `''`

So, if your pip/setuptools start to do odd things, check for this file first.